# Listview for Multiple model class

Tags: android, listview, generics, arraylist, adapter

how to create a listview adapter on Android Studio(Java) for multiple model class which extending parent class.

so :
gbpClass extends Money => ArrayList
eurClass extends Money  => ArrayList

I want to create list with gbpClass items and eurClass items. 1 button will show gbp list items. 1 button will show eur list items. But I will use 1 adapter class and it's Arraylist object can be contain gbp or eur list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your problem statement and with whatever information you have provided I think if you are only trying to show Euro and GBP data in your list then it's better not to complicate it and create single class for both

e.g.

```
data class Money(var amount: Double, var currency:String)
```

Comment: No, actually I want to use it for currencies, coins and golds. So not gbp or eur. I will fetch it from different source. If i use 1 model class like **money**  when i want to process different types it will be confusing.

Comment: so instead of using currency use assetType as a String Variable and you can rename your class as Asset

Comment: hmm, I dont know how can i do it. I am not good about annotations. But good idea sure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ArrayList<? extends Money> as a arraylist type?

The Difference between ArrayList<? extends Money> and ArrayList is that if you already have ArrayList list. you cannot point to

```
ArrayList<Money> list = gpbList; //as both type are different
```

You need to iterate the whole gbplist and put into the moneyList.

if you define your arraylist as ArrayList<? extends Money> you can do

```
 ArrayList<? extends Money> list = gpbList; //as both type are different
```

You don't need to iterate the list. As I already said both are very similar approach you can choose whatever suits you best. Thanks

Comment: can you explain your answer. type : currency and it extends Money. And type : Coin and it extends Money. Then  I need create an Arraylist it will keep both currency place and coin place. 


I thought, if I create an arraylist which contains Money items maybe I fix this issue. Because currency items or coin items already subtype of Money. But I wonder about doing this feature with polymorphism.

Comment: Yes you can add both subtype of money in the below list.
Money type is also fine both are very similiar approach
ArrayList<? extends Money>  list = new ArrayList<> ();

Comment: so you say if I define arraylist ``` ArrayList<? extends Money> list = new ArrayList<> (); ``` I can put different types which extends Money. And  it will represent ArrayList<Gbp> (); right?

Comment: yes correct, you can point list to ArrayList<Gbp> () as well